# kex_exchange_identification error when trying to use reverse ssh

Tags: ssh, openssl

When trying to use reverse ssh to ssh into a non-port forwarded pc by using
`ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 root@209.145.57.231` on the target,
and then doing the command
`ssh localhost -p 2222` on the server, it gives me the error `kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` no matter what I try

SSH Logs from -vvv:

````
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host```

output on target's side when trying to connect with -v
```debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 2222, originator 127.0.0.1 port 38136
debug1: getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([::1]:22) in progress, fd=7
debug1: channel 1: new [127.0.0.1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 22
debug1: channel 1: free: 127.0.0.1, nchannels 2```
````

Comment: Add at least one `-v` to the `ssh -R` and either _watch_ its terminal/window/console when you attempt to use the tunnel, or direct its outputs to a file and check the file afterwards.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 edited (although looks like for some reason code markdown messed up a little bit woops)

Answer (score 1):

After searching the error message "getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument" I found out that there wasn't an ssh handler or server running on the target (or client, the one that was doing the original ssh tunneling). After running on a simple golang ssh server, the error disappeared.